moderncv colors not showing up at bars
Here's my MWE
% !TEX spellcheck = en-US
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter. LaTeX Template Version 1.1 (9/12/12)
% This template has been downloaded from: http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
% Original author: Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com)
% License: CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
% Important note:
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same 
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes 
% used for structuring the document.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage[scale=.80]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name
%%%%%%%%%%%% custom addition %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{ulem} %enables the usage of \uline{} in stead of the base  \underline{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Doe} % Your last name
% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Curriculum Vitae}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Test Section}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESEARCH INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Research Interests}
\cvlistitem{Philosophy}
\cvlistitem{History}
\cvlistitem{Epidemiology}
\cvlistitem{Rocket Science}
\end{document} 

The output is like this (bars are always black but the bullets acquire colors as intended)

In addition, the gap between the name 'John Doe' and the 'Curriculam Vitae', seems to have changed (previously the later used to be closer to the horizontal line).
System: MacOS 15.1 beta with TexLive-2024 and XeTeX (same result in MacOS 14), I believe this problem originated once moved from TexLive-2023 to 2024.
Here's some related question-answers:

Creating additional color for moderncv
How to change color of the bar in ModernCV latex


The manual says (p10) Note. The color theme must be loaded before \moderncvstyle, which you don't do - does that change the output?

thanks! it worked. Now the question is how it was yielding the correct output even with 'wrong code' before but somehow with TexLive-2024 that's caught :D

@Marjin, would you like to add it as an answer? I'll accept it.

Presumably the code of moderncv is changed in the version that ships with TL2024 in such a way that the order as written in the manual is now required whereas before it wasn't - probably to make some other new functionality or bug fix possible.

Note that my name is first i and then j :) common mistake though. I can't really write an answer because I am unable to reproduce the issue, locally I don't have TL2024 installed and on Overleaf it is available but there your original code already works (it shows two blue bars and the section titles are also blue). You can self-answer if you want.

Thanks to Marijn, whose comments in the question lead to the answer, I'm just quoting him here.
Previously it worked even with the erroneous code, but "Presumably the code of moderncv is changed in the version that ships with TL2024 in such a way that the order as written in the manual is now required whereas before it wasn't - probably to make some other new functionality or bug fix possible." The reason is that the template source is old (last updated in 2016), but to make it work as intended, someone just needs to take care of this part like this:
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'

Quoting again "The manual says (p10) Note. The color theme must be loaded before \moderncvstyle"
